# Email doesn't sync anymore with Hotmail after the JellyBean update

Tags: email, active-sync, hotmail

My email app used to sync with Hotmail. After the Jellybean update it stopped syncing. I checked the settings: The peak and off-peak schedule are set to 'Push'. I also tested it with 15 minute pull. I always have to manually get the new messages.

The Exchange server settings ->Sync Email says 'Sync is turned off' with a green check mark. All the settings for Exchange are disabled and I can't change them.

Any ideas how to get the syncing working again?